# Issue with ion-radio-group with ngModel

Tags: angular, ionic4, ngmodel, ion-radio-group

I am using ion-radio-group with ngModel with hide/show functionality. Below is my UI code for view.

```
<ion-button (click)="showSection()" size="small" >show</ion-button>
<ion-button (click)="hideSection()" size="small" >Hide</ion-button>

<ion-list style="margin-bottom: 0px;" *ngIf="show">
  <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="payment.paytype">
    <ion-list-header>
      Select Payment Method
    </ion-list-header>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Online</ion-label>
  <ion-radio value="online"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>

   <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Token</ion-label>
      <ion-radio value="token"></ion-radio>
    </ion-item>
 </ion-radio-group>
</ion-list>
```

This is my hide/show code on controller.

```
show:boolean;payment={}

showSection()
{
    this.show = true;
}
hideSection()
{
    this.show = false;
}
```

Issue came when I select radio and performing hide show operation. My UI get freezes. I am using Ionic 4.

Note: if I am not selecting radio and doing hide/show no issue is coming. Issue is coming only when I selected the radio and then hide/show.

Comment: Can you carefully check your code and share it fully? it’s unclear how exactly you implemented the radio group :(

Comment: UI is same. For hide show defined 2 functions. thats it.

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the UI freezes when there's an infinite loop. especially in 2 way binding, you might encounter those kind of issues. 
Try to wrap the `ion-list` in a `div` and add the `ngIf` on the `div`.
and why are you using `async` function? it's not necessary.

Comment: yes i know something like infinite loop issue is happening. But i am not understanding how. async i'll remove. When i select radio then only issue is coming. but i have no idea how to handle this.